# How to test service workers offline mode in localhost?

Tags: javascript, service-worker

How can I test service workers in offline mode locally? I mean, localhost doesn't need internet access so it just keeps fetching all the files. Can I simulate offline in Firefox or Chrome somehow so I can see what happens when caching fails, or other things go wrong?

Comment: Hmm.. discovered a 'work offline' option in firefox. Click preferences > Developer, and then all the way at the bottom is work offline. That worked.... okay, that didn't work. It worked for css changes, but not html files. Very strange.

Comment: The work offline option didn't work for me because localhost was still available with Apache. I turned off Apache and then i was able to test the offline version of the page without any problems.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Chrome, you can simulate being offline in the DevTools' **`Application`** tab, inside the **`Service Workers`** panel. You will see there a checkbox that says **"Offline"**.[image]

Comment: Doesn't work for me. Came searching for an answer. Some (?!) network requests are still fetched "normally", even in offline mode. Which is causing me headaches for my first attempt to work with ServiceWorkers. I guess I'll have to stop nginx altogether...

Answer (score 1):

Also, you could go to the Networks tab and perform the same action.
Hope this helps :)

[image]