# Simulate no internet connection in testcafe tests

Tags: javascript, angular, service-worker, e2e-testing, testcafe

We have an SPA with service worker enabled. We needed to create an automated test to see if normal functions still work during offline/no internet connection. Our e2e test platform is testcafe and we've got no idea how to let testcafe do this.

Please guide us to a path on how this can be done.

Comment: Maybe this will help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43195485/how-to-test-service-workers-offline-mode-in-localhost

Comment: Hi, thanks for the help. I wish it would be as easy as that but I don't think the automated test can select that option on dev tools while it's running. I think you can pass profiles to the browser before the tests is run and setting to 'offline' might be one of those settings but the requirement is that it should be online first to load data into cache and turn off network connectivity afterwards before functional tests are done.

Comment: @john.solano Have you found a workaround so far?

Comment: We've just made it so that the server turns off before the offline tests begin. It's a bit easier to do when you run the servers via pm2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TestCafe does not provide any API to simulate offline mode. However, your idea sounds interesting as some browsers have a similar offline option out of the box. I recommend that you file your request at [TestCafe GitHub repo](https://github.com/DevExpress/testcafe/issues). I'll update this answer when this feature is available if any.